# HTACCESS - Get Path without filename

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering how to get just the request path without the file name, i.e. the folder where the requested file is in. Is that possible with the HTACCESS file or is there a variable like% {REQUEST_URI} without the filename?

I would then like to deposit the code in the htaccess in the / directory. I want to find out the folder path so that I don't have to enter the path for each subfolder individually. So when I access example.com/folder the code checks the same as it does on example.com/folder2.

So I want to redirect TO a maintenance page FROM every URL in whose same folder there is a maintenance.txt.

I would then like to check with an If statement in the folder of the requested file whether a certain file ("maintenance.txt") exists. Because I want to "block" every folder where this file exists in it.

Maybe it is possible with RegEx? I thought of something like this:

```
<If "-f %{FOLDER_OF_REQUESTED_FILE}/maintenance.txt">
   ErrorDocument 200 /assets/maintenance.html
</If>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in form of rules. Could you please also do mention FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect? that will give us more understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Well, I've changed that now. The problem is, I want to redirect from any URL that matches the -f if. I just need the folder to check whether the file is in it or not.

Comment: You can do this easily with ModRewrite.  Well, as easily as anything is with ModRewrite.  It is a complicated module, but it was designed for tasks like this.

Comment: Using mod_rewrite this should be possible by using one RewriteCond to capture the path portion out of the relative request URL, so that a second one can use a backreference to the match of the first one, and check if that plus `maintenance.txt` appended matches an existing file. If so, following RewriteRule then rewrites.